# how to pass all parameters of input XML document into output XML document

Tags: java, xml-parsing

general task is XML document processing. It'd be nice to have all input XML parameters usually given as `<p:MyDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="urn:where/to/look/4/schema" schemaVersion="1.3">`
passed to an output XML.
More specifically, how to get them from the input XML?
I can pass them (if I know them in advance) as

```
Element rootElement = document.createElementNS("urn:hard/coded", root);         
rootElement.setAttribute("schemaVersion", "myWish");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the attribute details using `document.getAttributes()`